# Exclude AirDrop and Add to Reading List from apps build with iOS 6 SDK

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I have a `UIActivityViewController` in my iOS 6 app, I am pushing an update but I'm not yet compiling it with iOS 7 SDK.

Is there any way to disable Add to Reading List and AirDrop in my `UIActivityViewController` in iOS7 without recompiling with iOS 7 SDK?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`excludedActivityTypes` is a valid property in iOS 6.0 and above, so you can leverage that.  The constants you need (`UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList` and `UIActivityTypeAirDrop`) are not available so what you can do is use their literal values (most likely the same as the variable name) until you recompile with the iOS 7 SDK (Which I suggest you do.  It is not likely that Apple would change a constant value but it is better programming practice to use the variable instead of its literal).  I imagine these values would be ignored in iOS 6.x and not cause any problems since any `UIActivity` can define its own name so the system has no way of validating a given type.  It most likely will just add them to an internal ignore list.

Comment: Thanks borrrden, it works. For anyone wondering what the string value of those symbols: `@"com.apple.UIKit.activity.AirDrop"` and `@"com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList"`.

Comment: @ Enrico Susatyo

This method is legal if I am apply, apple is reject the app or not.

@"com.apple.UIKit.activity.AirDrop" and @"com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList"

Comment: @iOSDev Yup, my app has been approved a few weeks ago.