# Customize UIActivityViewController to only show selected apps, excluding AirDrop functionality and bottom row of actions?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios7

In iOS 7, is it possible to customize the UIActivityViewController (sample image shown below) such that only a few apps are displayed? For instance, we only want to show iMessage, WeChat, Line, KaKao, Skype, Kik, and Facebook Messenger (not Facebook proper).

Our goal is to permit sharing of images from our app to other apps, but we want to simplify the interface as much as possible and only show supported apps. Nothing more.

From the Apple documentation, it's clear how to exclude actions like saving to the camera roll or assigning to contact or printing, but what if we want to exclude the top row (i.e., AirDrop) and bottom row (i.e., share actions) altogether?

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486850/exclude-airdrop-and-add-to-reading-list-from-apps-build-with-ios-6-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It's what the second param (applicationActivities) of this does:

```
- (id)initWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems applicationActivities:(NSArray *)applicationActivities;
```

Hand it an array of [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivity), determine the services it presents.

Comment: cool, thanks! also is it possible to control the order that the apps appear? or should this be a separate question?

Comment: seems related... I haven't tested this but pretty sure you can control order via the order of the passed array.

Comment: thanks again, @danh! the doc you provided only lists certain apps like weibo and twitter. how do we identify the end points for apps like kakao, line, whatsapp, skype, and other apps?

Comment: I think the sdk is limited to apps that apple has chosen to support.

Comment: hmm weird bc some apps like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/big-emoji-for-texting-facebook/id501840899?mt=8 support path kakao line and others. no clue how they do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look like all you need to do is to set properly the `excludedActivityTypes` property. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  and my comment.

Comment: also is it possible to control the order that the apps appear? or should this be a separate question?